# Codeigniter auto suggestion text box

Tags: codeigniter, autosuggest

I'm using codeigniter in my project and want to implement a text box which suggests related word s from the data base. In this one I want to get the ID of the selected vehicle. But so far I was only able to retrieve the vehicle names with out IDs.

The code so far,

Model

```
function searchVehicle($name){
        $this->db->like('Name', $name, 'both');
        return $this->db->get('vw_vehicle_search')->result();
    }
```

Controller

```
public function vehicle_search(){
        $this->load->model('model_vehicle');
        if(isset($_GET['term'])){
            $result = $this->model_vehicle->searchVehicle($_GET['term']);
            if(count($result)>0){
                foreach($result as $object)
                    $arr_result[] = $object->Name;

                echo json_encode($arr_result);
            }
        }
    }
```

View

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#vehicle_name').autocomplete({
                    source: "<?php echo base_url();?>vehicle/vehicle_search/?"
                });
            });
        </script>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <?php
        $input_data = array(
        'name'  => 'vehicle_name',
        'id' => 'vehicle_name',
        'class' => 'form-control'
        );
        echo form_input($input_data)?>
    </div>
```

How can I pass the id of the vehicle with this one and get the id when i select a vehicle to insert to the db.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried setting vehicle_id as key of your `$arr_result` array??

Comment: then it will display only the vehicle id. but I want to search it by vehicle name

Answer (score 0):

Try it in this way:

controller:

```
public function vehicle_search(){
    $this->load->model('model_vehicle');
    if(isset($_GET['term'])){
        $result = $this->model_vehicle->searchVehicle($_GET['term']);
        if(count($result)>0){
            foreach($result as $object)
                $arr_result[] = array( 'label' => $object->Name, 'value' => $object->id);

            echo json_encode($arr_result);
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#vehicle_name').autocomplete({
        source: "<?php echo base_url();?>vehicle/vehicle_search/?",
        select: function(event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#vehicle_name").val(ui.item.label);
            //$("#vehicle_name-hidden").val(ui.item.value);
        },
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#vehicle_name").val(ui.item.label);
        }
    });
});
```